# Error con constructores de Java

Tags: java, clase, herencia, constructor

Tengo mi clase padre `Aula` y mis subclases `aulaTeorica` y `aulaPratica`. Anexo las respectivas clases.

### clase "Aula"

```
public class Aula {

    private String nombreAula,ubicacionAula;
    private int capacidadAula;
   
    public Aula(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula) {
        this.nombreAula = nombreAula;
        this.ubicacionAula = ubicacionAula;
        this.capacidadAula = capacidadAula;
    }

    public String getNombreAula() {
        return nombreAula;
    }
   
    public void setNombreAula(String nombreAula) {
        this.nombreAula = nombreAula;
    }

    public String getUbicacionAula() {
        return ubicacionAula;
    }
 
    public void setUbicacionAula(String ubicacionAula) {
        this.ubicacionAula = ubicacionAula;
    }

    public int getCapacidadAula() {
        return capacidadAula;
    }
   
    public void CapacidadAula(int capacidadAula){
        this.capacidadAula = capacidadAula;
    }
}
```

### subclase "AulaTeorica"

```
public class AulaTeorica extends Aula {

    public AulaTeorica(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula) {
        super(nombreAula, ubicacionAula, capacidadAula);
    }

    private String tipoPupitre;

    public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre) {
        this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre;
    }

    public String getTipoPupitre() {
        return tipoPupitre;
    }
   
    public void setTipoPupitre(String tipoPupitre) {
        this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre;
    }
}
```

Obtengo el error:

> *public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre)
>
> Constructor Aula in class Aula canot be applied to given types.
> Required: String, String, int
> Found: No arument
> Reason: Actual and formal argument list differ in length*

### Subclase "AulaPractica"

```
public class AulaPractica extends Aula {

    public AulaPractica(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula) {
        super(nombreAula, ubicacionAula, capacidadAula);
    }

    private int altavoces, videoCamara;

    public AulaPractica(int altavoces, int videoCamara) {
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
        this.videoCamara = videoCamara;
    }

    public int getAltavoces() {
        return altavoces;
    }

    public void setAltavoces(int altavoces) {
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
    }

    public int getVideoCamara() {
        return videoCamara;
    }

    public void setVideoCamara(int videoCamara) {
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
    }
}
```

Obtengo el error:

> *public AulaPractica(int altavoces, int videoCamara)
>
> Constructor Aula in class Aula canot be applied to given types.
> Required: String, String, int
> Found: No arument
> Reason: Actual and formal argument list differ in length*

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, gracias!

---

Tengo entendido que es pq tengo dos clases que se llaman igual. Anexo imagen de muestra con la clase AulaPractica.

[image: Descripción del código con explicación]

Comment: Me parece que el error ocurre en el contexto donde usas las clases.¿Podrías agregarlo en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]?

Comment: Tu constructor no tiene los mismos parámetros que tu clase. 

Public AulaTeorica(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula) {}  

y tu constructor solo tiene un parametro: 
public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre){ } y el error marca que requiere de una buena sintaxis... STRING, STRING, INT y solo tienes un STRING en el constructor

Comment: Está heredando String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula;

Mi sub clase AulaPractica solo me pide identificar int altavoces, int videoCamaras;

Siendo el caso ¿Las variables de mi sub clase tienen que coincidir con las que está heredando?

Comment: Si vas a hacer un constructor de una clase debes ocupar todos los parametros de la clase... el mismo error menciona que los argumentos que tienes que llenar es String, String, int...

Comment: Por favor pon el contexto donde usas las clases para poder tener una visión global del problema. Puedes pulsar en [edit]  para hacer aclaraciones en la misma pregunta, el área de respuestas es sólo para respuestas, no para aclaraciones sobre la propia pregunta. Aparte de lo que dice @BetaM, puede que estás alimentando mal a la clase, en el contexto. Pon el contexto.

Comment: Según leo los errores, creo que es necesario que muestras la manera en que incializas objetos con estas clases. Tal vez si muestras tu `Main`...

Answer (score 1):

La clase `Aula` define un constructor con tres parámetros: 2 de tipo `String` y uno de tipo `int`.

Cuando no declaras ningún constructor en alguna clase, se entiende que de manera implícita tienes disponible el constructor por defecto (sin parámetros). Pero en el momento en que creas un constructor con una signatura diferente (algún parámetro), el constructor por defecto ya no se agrega implícitamente en tu clase. Pero lo puedes agregar tú explícitamente.

En las clases `AulaTeorica` y `AulaPractica` tienes también constructores con varios parámetros. En uno haces la llamada al constructor del padre, mediante `super(...)`. Pero en otro no haces la llamada a `super(String, String, int)`. Ese es el error.

Es debido a que cuando no llamas a `super`, se agrega un llamada de manera implícita al constructor por defecto de la clase padre, pero como la clase padre no tiene constructor por defecto, tienes que agregar explícitamente una llamada al constructor del padre con 3 parámetros.

```
public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre){       
    super("", "", 0);  // Llamada al constructor del padre
    this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre;
}
```

Otra opción es definir un constructor sin parámetros en la clase padre.

```
public class Aula {
    // ...
    public Aula() {
        // Implementación (puede estar vacía)
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto no es así: *Pero en el momento en que creas un constructor con una signatura diferente (algún parámetro), el constructor por defecto ya no se agrega implícitamente en tu clase.* El constructor por defecto existe siempre en la clase, nunca deja de existir.

Comment: De la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html): _You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors_. En español: No tienes que proveer a tu clase con ningún constructor [...]. **El compilador provee automáticamente un constructor por defecto sin parámetros a cualquier clase sin constructores**.

Comment: Correcto, justo lo que he dicho en el anterior comentario.

Comment: @A.Cedano La parte importante es lo que está colocando Eequis en negrillas: _"... a cualquier clase sin constructores"_.... dado que *Aula* tiene un constructor, el constructor por defecto desaparece y habría que colocar un constructor sin parametros de forma explícita para que la llamada implícita a super() que hace un constructor si no se hace una llamada a un constructor de la supreclase funcione.

Comment: @A.Cedano en la misma documentación que he enlazado antes pone lo siguiente: _the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor_. En español: **el compilador se quejará si la superclase no tiene un constructor sin parámetros**. Esto implica necesariamente que el constructor por defecto no se agrega implícitamente siempre. Como he publicado, en el momento en el que pones un constructor en tu clase, el compilador ya no inserta el constructor por defecto de manera implícita. Habría que codificarlo explícitamente para volver a tenerlo disponible.

Comment: Tenía entendido que las clases tienen siempre un constructor por defecto. Haré pruebas para verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Correccion, me refiero al contructor AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre). AulaTeorica extiende de Aula y Aula tiene un contructor.
Dentro del codigo AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre) debes llamar a super para instanciar la clase extendida Aula.

```
public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre){
    //Aqui instancio la clase extendida Aula con super pasando valores por defectos. Aqui debes poner los tuyos que mas acorde para tu app.       
    super("", "", 0);
    this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre;
   
}
```

Comment: Al inicio de la clase aulaPractica se llama al método super con los atributos de la clase Aula

Comment: Joel, me refiero al constructor public AulaTeorica(String tipoPupitre). Actualice el código.

Comment: Considera mejorar tu respuesta, siendo más especifico del por qué es una solución al problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando mal la herencia, seguramente estas intentado pasar los int al constructor, pero los mismos no aparecen en la firma del método, ni tampoco aparecen dentro del constructor.
Tus clases deberían estar planteadas de la siguiente manera:

Clase aula:

```
public abstract class Aula // Para evitar crear instancias de la clase madre
{
    private String nombreAula,ubicacionAula;
    private int capacidadAula;
   
    public Aula(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula) {
        this.nombreAula = nombreAula;
        this.ubicacionAula = ubicacionAula;
        this.capacidadAula = capacidadAula;
    }

    public String getNombreAula() {
        return nombreAula;
    }
   
    public void setNombreAula(String nombreAula) {
        this.nombreAula = nombreAula;
    }

    public String getUbicacionAula() {
        return ubicacionAula;
    }
 
    public void setUbicacionAula(String ubicacionAula) {
        this.ubicacionAula = ubicacionAula;
    }

    public int getCapacidadAula() {
        return capacidadAula;
    }
   
    public void CapacidadAula(int capacidadAula){
        this.capacidadAula = capacidadAula;
    }
}
```

Aula Teorica:

```
public class AulaTeorica extends Aula
{
    private String tipoPupitre;

    public AulaTeorica(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula,String tipoPupitre) // asi debe ser el constructor
    {
        super(nombreAula, ubicacionAula, capacidadAula);
        this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre; // aca estas inicializando la variable de la clase hija.
    }

    public String getTipoPupitre() {
        return tipoPupitre;
    }
   
    public void setTipoPupitre(String tipoPupitre) {
        this.tipoPupitre = tipoPupitre;
    }
    
}
```

Clase aula practica:

```
public class AulaPractica extends Aula
{
    private int altavoces, videoCamara;

    public AulaPractica(String nombreAula, String ubicacionAula, int capacidadAula,int altavoces, int videoCamara) {
        super(nombreAula, ubicacionAula, capacidadAula);
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
        this.videoCamara = videoCamara;
    }

    public int getAltavoces() {
        return altavoces;
    }

    public void setAltavoces(int altavoces) {
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
    }

    public int getVideoCamara() {
        return videoCamara;
    }

    public void setVideoCamara(int videoCamara) {
        this.altavoces = altavoces;
    }
}
```

prueba este código, te debería compilar sin problema